# Strange Behaviour of the border control in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I added the below code in the `usercontrol`, Hence I could see the border in the `usercontrol` itself. But the problem is when I added this `usercontrol` into `ManinWindow.xaml` the border was missing 
only the label was displaying. What could be a problem?

```
<Border BorderBrush="Red" CornerRadius="10">            
  <Label  Content="Take Up"></Label>          
</Border>
```

Your solution would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need a BorderThickness Property;

```
<Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Red" CornerRadius="10">            
  <Label  Content="Take Up"></Label>          
</Border>
```

For Instance